# Does twitter REST API return user's friend that only uses my app like facebook does?

Tags: twitter

I want twitter REST API to return only a twitter user's friend. But all the user's friend must use my app. I implemented it using TweetInvi API but all I did was imported all the user's friend and check on my database if his friend exist or not. So, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Twitter does not provide that details. 
Refer: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: Bummer. Thanks though